Normal Subgroups of Virtually Simple Group
I have a very elementary question, but I cannot answer it. My question is,

If $G$ is a virtually simple group, does $G$ have finitely many normal subgroup?

I think we can assume WLOG that the simple subgroup $H$ of finite index is also normal. Any normal subgroup of $G$ must intersect $H$ trivially or contain $H$. I was going to try to define a map from set of normal subgroups of $G$ to normal subgroups of $G/H$, and show the fibers are all finite, but I couldn't see why that was true.
As far as possible counterexamples, I was initially thinking about I could get one from direct products of form $G \times F$ for $G$ simple and $F$ finite, but that clearly won't work (right?)

What did you try to solve this?

@MoisheKohan Not very much. I couldn't get very far. I think we can assume WLOG that the simple subgroup $H$ of finite index is also normal. Any normal subgroup of $G$ must intersect $H$ trivially or contain $H$. I was going to try to define a map from set of normal subgroups of $G$ to normal subgroups of $G/H$, and show the fibers are all finite, but I couldn't see why that was true.

All of your comment should have gone into the question. As i is, the question will probably be closed for missing context.

Let $H$ be a simple group of finite index in $G$. Just to get it out of the way, some assumptions on $H$ we can make:

$H$ is infinite.

If $H$ is finite, then so is $G$ and clearly $G$ has finitely many
normal subgroups. So we may assume $H$ is infinite.

$H$ has trivial centre.

Since $H$ is simple and the centre is always a normal subgroup, we either have $Z(H) = 1$ or $Z(H) = H$. In the latter case, $H$ would be abelian. But an abelian simple group must be cyclic of prime order and hence finite.

$H$ is normal in $G$.

Indeed, let $C$ be the normal core of $H$ in $G$. Then $C$ is also normal in $H$. But $C$ will also have
finite index in $G$, and hence in $H$. Since $H$ is infinite, this
means that $C \neq 1$, and because $H$ is simple, we must have $C =
   H$. So $H$ is normal.
Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Then $N \cap H$ is a normal subgroup of $H$, so either $N \cap H = H$ or $N \cap H = 1$. We show that in both cases, only finitely many $N$ can exist.

$N \cap H = H$. In this case, $N$ is a finite union of cosets $G/H$. But there are only finitely many cosets, so in turn there are only finitely many normal subgroups $N$ that contain $H$.

$N \cap H = 1$. Note that in this case elements of $N$ and $H$ always commute.
Let $g \in G$ arbitrarily, and consider the (left) coset $gH$.
Suppose that there exist $h_1, h_2 \in H$ such that for each $h_i$, there
exists a normal subgroup $N_i$ with $h_ig \in N_i$ and $N_i \cap H =
1$. Then $h_1g$ and $h_2g$ both commute with $H$, hence so does
$$h_1g(h_2g)^{-1} = h_1gg^{-1}h_2^{-1} = h_1h_2^{-1},$$
and then $h_1h_2^{-1} \in Z(H) = 1$. So $h_1 = h_2$.
So each coset $gH$ contains at most one element that belongs to a normal subgroup $N$ with $N \cap H = 1$. Let $g_1H, \ldots, g_nH$ be the cosets of $H$ and (after rearrangement of the indices) assume that $g_1H, \ldots, g_kH$ contain a (unique!) element $g_i h_i$ that belongs to a normal subgroup $N$ with $N \cap H = 1$, and $g_{k+1}H, \ldots, g_nH$ do not contain such element. Then any normal subgroup $N$ with $N \cap H = 1$ is a subset of $\{ g_1h_1, \ldots, g_kh_k\}$. This is a finite set, so only finitely many such $N$ can exist.


